# A well founded relation $R$ on a class $A$ does not need to be set-like

Tags: set-theory, relations, transfinite-induction

The theorem that justifies transfinite induction on a class states the following:

> *Assume that $R$ is well-founded and set-like on $A$, and that $X$ is a non-empty sub-class of $A$. Then $X$ has an $R$-minimal element.*

However, with the Axiom of Foundation, we can eliminate the requirement that $R$ must be set-like.  My question is regarding a certain step in the proof of such.  Here is what I have.

For $x \in X$, let $f(x) = \min\{\text{rank}(z): z\in X \wedge zRx\}.$  (Here $\text{rank}(z)$ is $\text{rank}_{V,\in}(z)$, this is where we need Foundation.)  This function essentially corresponds each element $x \in X$ to the lowest rank of a set which is below $x$ in the relation $R$.  This function exists because any class of ordinals has a minimal element.  The goal is to find a sub*set* of $X$ whose minimal element is also minimal in $X$.  Suppose we can find a $\gamma$ such that $X \cap V_\gamma$ is non-empty and $\forall x \in X \cap V_\gamma [f(x) < \gamma]$.

Let $y$ be minimal in $X \cap V_\gamma.$  Then $f(y) = \emptyset$, for assume that $f(y) = \alpha$.  Then by our definition of $f$, there is a $z \in X$ such that $zRy$ and $\text{rank}(z) = \alpha$.  Then, because $\alpha < \gamma$ (by our choice of $\gamma$) we get $z \in X \cap V_\gamma$.  But then $y$ is not minimal in $X \cap V_\gamma$ and thus $f(y) = \emptyset$.  Therefore, there is no $z \in X \wedge xRy$ and $y$ is minimal in $X$.

My question is: how do we produce $\gamma$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with any ordinal $\gamma_0$ such that $X\cap V_{\gamma_0}$ is nonempty.  Recursively define $\gamma_{n+1}=\sup \{f(x):x\in X\cap V_{\gamma_n}\}+1$.  This gives a sequence of ordinals $\gamma_n$ for each $n\in\omega$; let $\gamma$ be their supremum.  Then any $x\in X\cap V_\gamma$ is in $V_{\gamma_n}$ for some $n$, and so $f(x)<\gamma_{n+1}\leq\gamma$ by definition.